# How to find if free shipping is enabled on Magento 1.9

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am using Magento 1.9.3 and writing a php if/else statement on view.phtml in app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product

I need to find out if free shipping is enabled or not in admin for my php if/else statement. I can get the order total with Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/freeshipping/free_shipping_subtotal') but also need to find out if free shipping is enabled or not. Is there a way of finding if free shipping is enabled or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can get free shipping enable/disable status by below code

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/freeshipping/active')
```